# Issues with CSS for text input size - possible inheritance problems

Tags: html, css

I'm trying to create a table with text inputs but I'm having some issues getting the textboxes to size properly. When copied to an existing project, the textbox is 4px larger all around. It's a unique name but it's still inheriting properties and I can't figure out how to avoid this. The table dimensions are proper, just not the input.

Here's the CSS

```
.medium_input{
    display: block;
    width:90%; 
    height:30px;
    font-size:12px;
    padding: 0;
    margin: 0;
}
.left_half {
    width: 49%;
    float: left;
}

.g_info_table {
    width:100%;
    margin-bottom: 0;
}

.g_info_table tr td {
    vertical-align: middle;
    height: 40px;
    border-bottom: none;
}

.g_info_table tr:nth-child(even) {
    background-color: #FFF;
}
```

Here's the HTML (I'm using knockout)

```
<div data-bind ="visible: gInfoDiv()">
    <div class = "left_half">
        <table class = "g_info_table">
                <tr><td width = "100px">First Name</td><td><input data-bind="value: firstName" type="text" class = "medium_input" ></td></tr>
                <tr><td width = "100px">Last Name</td><td><input data-bind="value: lastName" type="text" class = "medium_input"></td></tr>
                <tr><td width = "100px">Address</td><td><input data-bind="value: address" type="text" class = "medium_input"></td></tr>
                <tr><td width = "100px">City</td><td><input data-bind="value: city" type="text" class = "medium_input"></td></tr>
        </table>
    </div>
</div>
```

Comment: If you inspect element in ff/chrome, does it give a hint as to where it's inheriting undesirable CSS from? Are you using a reset (although this might not be the cause of your problem)?

Comment: One thing is that you are not accounting for the border line, it equates to 1 px on each side.

Comment: @JuanGonzales I'm talking about inside the border. It's still 2px difference all the way around even including the border.

Comment: You should specify what exactly is 4px larger than what. You should describe what happens, instead of assuming (most probably wrongly) that inheritance is the cause. It sounds like you are using in the code in a context that is not disclosed at all in the question and that causes some CSS settings to be overridden.

Answer (score 0):

I would add a reset on the table container `left_half` before the rest of the table styles are loaded:

```
.left_half * {
    margin: 0;
    padding: 0;
    border: none;
}

.medium_input{
    display: block;
    width:90%; 
    height:30px;
    font-size:12px;
    padding: 0;
    margin: 0;
}
.left_half {
    width: 49%;
    float: left;
}

.g_info_table {
    width:100%;
    margin-bottom: 0;
}

.g_info_table tr td {
    vertical-align: middle;
    height: 40px;
    border-bottom: none;
}

.g_info_table tr:nth-child(even) {
    background-color: #FFF;
}
```

I'm no expert but that's what you do when you can't control the inheritance.